# Now() function with time trim

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba, ms-access-2003

So the function `=Now()`....is there a way I can use this and only get the date, not the time?

or is there just a function for this idea?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There is a [Date function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa227520%28v=VS.60%29.aspx).

Comment: so how do I use this?? i can use =Now() in VBA to get the current date and time, but it will not allow me to enter Date() or =Date(). it automatically takes away the () and the function does not seem to work the same way as =Now()

Comment: Date is the correct function to use. And yes, in the code editor, it will remove the ()

Comment: ah i see...i stand corrected. mistake else where was throwing me off. apologies...and thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Dates in VBA are just floating point numbers, where the integer part represents the date and the fraction part represents the time. So in addition to using the `Date` function as tlayton says (to get the *current* date) you can also cast a date value to a integer to get the date-part from an arbitrary date: `Int(myDateValue)`.

Comment: Why would anyone do that when there's a function specifically defined to return the integer part alone? That is, why make two function calls when one will do the job?

Comment: I interpret Dean's suggestion as a way to understand the nature of Date/Time values, not as a general substitute for `Date()`.  From that standpoint I think his suggestion is very useful.  +1

Answer (score 11):

```
DateValue(CStr(Now()))
```

That's the best I've found. If you have the date as a string already you can just do:

```
DateValue("12/04/2012 04:56:15")
```

or

```
DateValue(*DateStringHere*)
```

Hope this helps someone...

Answer (score 5):

I would prefer to make a function that doesn't work with strings:

```
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : RemoveTimeFromDate
' Author    : berend.nieuwhof
' Date      : 15-8-2013
' Purpose   : removes the time part of a String and returns the date as a date
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'
Public Function RemoveTimeFromDate(DateTime As Date) As Date


    Dim dblNumber As Double

    RemoveTimeFromDate = CDate(Floor(CDbl(DateTime)))

End Function

Private Function Floor(ByVal x As Double, Optional ByVal Factor As Double = 1) As Double
    Floor = Int(x / Factor) * Factor
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use Format$(Now(), "Short Date") or whatever date format you want.  Be aware, this function will return the Date as a string, so using Date() is a better approach.

Comment: what would i need to do to the above to get a date format of 28-Sep-10? Thanks I appreciate it!

Comment: Format$(Date(), "dd-MMM-yy").  There is also the Format function which returns a variant.  If you know you're going to need a string to be returned, use the Format$ function.

Comment: In code, you can generally use # to surround the date. 

Eg: #09/28/2010#

However, the above can be messed up by date formatting, so another choice is dateserial() command. The syntax is dateserial(year,month,day), so 

DateSerial(2010,9,28)

Comment: wow thanks guys! i learned a lot with a simple question!! i love to do so because I am an aspiring student! thanks very much!

Comment: You can also restore the date datatype from a string representation of a date by passing it through the DateValue() function. But this question is completely wrongheaded in recommending using Format() just to get the date part.

Answer (score 1):

Paste this function in your Module and use it as like formula

```
Public Function format_date(t As String)
    format_date = Format(t, "YYYY-MM-DD")
End Function
```

for example in Cell A1 apply this formula

```
=format_date(now())
```

it will return in YYYY-MM-DD format. Change any format (year month date) as your wish.